# South Africa visitor visa

Tags: customs-and-immigration, visa-free-entry, south-africa

My daughter visited South Africa earlier this year for 3 weeks and was given a 90-day visitor visa. She has been home for 2 months but wants to go back to South Africa for the summer (approximately 2 months) before starting Uni. Her original visa is due to expire approximately 1 week after she returns to SA. Will she be given a new 90-day visa when she goes back, even if her original one has some time left on it, or will there be a problem?

Comment: Does she have a visa? If she didn't go to a South African embassy, she does **not**, and yes, she'll be given a new 90-day visa-free stay, since she returned home.

Comment: Thank you - no she doesn't have a visa, just a 90 day tourist entry visa given at the border.

Comment: You keep saying that word. It definitely does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: @Roz South Africa does not issue visas at the border, so what she has is an entry stamp. A visa (even oin arrival) is a condition to enter, an entry stamp means you **did** enter

Answer (score 2):

Because she returned home after visiting South Africa, she can get another 90 days without a visa.

However, how long she can stay is always up to the officer, and they may want proof of ties to her home country if she says she'll stay for 2 months (which she has to say if asked), so she should bring a return flight confirmation, Hotel booking confirmation and a letter from her prospective University.